# Cannot insert .eps figure into LuaLaTeX compilation

Tags: graphics, errors, luatex, eps

I'm trying to insert a .eps figure into my document.
I'm using LuaLaTeX.
I have already tried to remove the ".eps" extension from the `\includegraphics{}` command, but it didn't work. Makes no difference (do not compile)
It always says the error:

> Unknown graphics extension: .eps

I also tried the package epstopdf, but that didn't work either.
It shows the error:

> Package pdftex.def error: File 'fig/VocSOCGeneric-eps-converted-to-.pdf not f [I think it is "not found"].

In the path "fig/" no pdf is created (and no pdf is created in the project directory also).
I also tried to insert the `-shell-escape` and `--enable-write18` commands, but unsuccessfully.

It seems that all alternatives from converting eps to pdf are only suitable for pdfLaTeX, and not for LuaLaTex. Also, there is almost no documentation about eps figures AND LuaLaTeX, leading me to think that LuaLaTeX should deal naturally with eps graphics. But I don't know how!

Code example below.

```
\documentclass[addressstd,a4paper,10pt]{report}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage[2015/01/01]{latexrelease}

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{url}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}

\RequirePackage{luatextra}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{chngcntr}

%\RequirePackage{epstopdf}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}

\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=endash,         justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang}

\begin{document}

    Text before

    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Curva Característica Voc SOC de uma bateria Li-ion NCA.}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/VocSOCGeneric.eps}
    \label{fig:cap1VocSOC}
    \end{figure}

    Text after

\end{document}
```

Comment: PDF images work! 
Only EPS don't work!

Comment: Remove the `.eps` extension in your `\includegraphics` lines

Comment: epstopdf works fine with lualatex, but if you have miktex you must call lualatex with `--shell-escape` as shell-restricted is not activated see  https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2415/

Comment: @JosephWright I have already tried removing .eps extension from the comand \includegraphics. Doesn't work

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried the --shell-escape option before, but it didn't work. But now that you told about that, I looked again in some foruns and realized that the problem was the position of the command --shell-escape in the line. I will publish in the answer.

Comment: I tested it, epstopdf works. But in my case the graphic was in the same directory as the tex file.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

I made it work. And the answer is simple. As `--shell-escape` is an option, it should be placed before the .tex (`%wm`).
My problem was that I was placing it after the .tex. These examples can explain better:

This one worked:

```
-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "%wm"
```

This one was not working before:

```
-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" --shell-escape
```

Thanks to UlrikeFischer, I had this idea after your comment.

Comment: Please clean up your answer to make it readable.  A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)!

Comment: In your solution, do you need the Package "epstopdf"?